# Unity3d and Firebase error downloading files gave me error. Error 403

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

Greeting,
After testing with Firebase with Unity3d, and I managed to download an image. So, I trying to download an assetbundle from a new scene.

After I setup the code everything, it gave me this error.

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.Storage.StorageException: Permission denied. Could not perform this operation  Http Code: 403
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Firebase.Storage.StorageException: Permission denied. Could not perform this operation  Http Code: 403<---

UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
DownloadController:<DownloadStarted>b__6_0(Task`1) (at Assets/DownloadController.cs:118)
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback()
```

Do anyone have this issue before?

Comment: I suspect that this may be related to security rules. Would you mind sharing your rules? Also, if you are signing in, ensuring that you wait on the async result of signing in (or verifying that `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CurrentUser` is non-null before downloading anything)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. and I forgot to close this question, I managed to solve it. I forgot to call the Firebase Auth at the beginning.